# SSIS package source - differences

Tags: ssis

We currently run our SSIS packages as SQL server agent job with the package source as "file system"

what are the benefits or differences if we import the package into Integration services and change the package source to reflect the new location?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can store your packages: on the file system or in the msdb database. Each storage option has its own pros and cons and which option you choose will be based on what is more important to you. It also depends on scenario under which you are developing your packages such as FileSystem for ease of use but MSDB better for security purpose

Functionality Best in MSDB   -

- Security : assign package roles to each package to designate who can see or execute the package. The packages can also be encrypted
- Execution Speed :

Functionality Best in File System -

- Backup and Recovery : Easy to backup the folders and files
- Deployment : File system deployments are much simpler but less sophisticated. To deploy packages onto the file system, you must only copy them into the directory for the package store.
- Troubleshooting
- Availability

You can have look of below article for more details.

- [SSIS Package Deployment Method – File System or Server](http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2010/01/30/ssis-package-deployment-method-file-system-or-server/)
- [What are the advantages/disadvantages of storing SSIS packages to MSDB vs File System](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20What%20are%20the%20advantages_disadvantages%20of%20storing%20SSIS%20packages%20to%20MSDB%20vs%20File%20System.htm)
- [Deploy to file system or SQL Server](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/02/20/SSIS_3A00_-Deploy-to-file-system-or-SQL-Server.aspx)